# Navigation not staying at Bottom of Slider

Tags: html, css

In my slider, it's supposed to have the image, the caption and credit below that, and then the navigation at the bottom. For some reason though, my navigation is not staying at the bottom of the slider, but sliding up over the caption to sit right under the image slide and I can't figure out why. I believe it's a CSS issue, but everything looks sound to me.

If anyone could help me out it would be greatly appreciated. I've created a JSFiddle as well as added the code here: http://jsfiddle.net/t534v/3/

CSS:

```
body {
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
    font-family:'Abel', sans-serif;
    font-size: 17px;
    line-height: 23px;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
    width: 580px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    margin: 20px auto;
    padding: 15px;
}
.postContainer {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.postContainer h1 {
    font-family:'Medula One', cursive;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 46px;
    font-size: 52px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
/************SLIDESHOW************/
 .slideshow {
    background-color: #DEDFCC;
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    position: relative;
}
.slideContainer {
     background-color: #DEDFCC;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
.slide {
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #C9B7B7;
}
.slideMiddle {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.slide img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.slideInfo {
    width: 100%;
    height: 80%;
    padding: 10px;
}
.slideNav {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #C9B7B7;
    color: #DEDFCC;
    position:relative;
}
.prevSlide {
    width: 33.3%;
    float: left;
}
.nextSlide {
    width: 33.3%;
    float: right;
    text-align: right;
}
.slideCount {
    width: 23.3%;
    text-align: center;
    position:absolute;
    left:40%;
}
.slideCredit {
    width: 100%;
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 12px;
}
.fix {
    clear: both;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="postContainer">
    <h1>Liam Payne Hair Evolution</h1>
    <p>Liam Payne has perhaps gone through the most hairstyle changes of any member of 1D!  Check them out below!</p>

                <div class="slideshow">           
                <div class="slideContainer">
                  <div class="slide">
                    <span class="slideMiddle"></span><img src="http://onedirectionconnection.com/jquery/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/2010.jpg">
                  </div>
                  <div class="slideInfo">
                    <p class="slideCaption">
                      <p>2
                      Liam Payne Hair Evolution</p>
                      Please excuse these horrible captions.                    </p>
                    <p class="slideCredit">
                      Google                    </p>
                  </div> <!--slideInfo end-->
                  <div class="fix"></div>
                </div> <!--slideContainer end-->
               <!--end if each if-->


                <div class="slideContainer">
                  <div class="slide">
                    <span class="slideMiddle"></span><img src="http://onedirectionconnection.com/jquery/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/2011.jpg">
                  </div>
                  <div class="slideInfo">
                    <p class="slideCaption">
                      <p>3 Liam Payne Hair Evolution</p>
                      I'm ashamed, but they're necessary...                 </p>
                    <p class="slideCredit">
                      Freebie                   </p>
                  </div> <!--slideInfo end-->
                  <div class="fix"></div>
                </div> <!--slideContainer end-->
               <!--end if each if-->


                <div class="slideContainer">
                  <div class="slide">
                    <span class="slideMiddle"></span><img src="http://onedirectionconnection.com/jquery/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/2012.jpg">
                  </div>
                  <div class="slideInfo">
                    <p class="slideCaption">
                      <p>4 Liam Payne Hair Evolution</p>
                      Cutie patootie...                 </p>
                    <p class="slideCredit">
                      Getty                 </p>
                  </div> <!--slideInfo end-->
                  <div class="fix"></div>
                </div> <!--slideContainer end-->
               <!--end if each if-->


                <div class="slideContainer">
                  <div class="slide">
                    <span class="slideMiddle"></span><img src="http://onedirectionconnection.com/jquery/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/2013.jpg">
                  </div>
                  <div class="slideInfo">
                    <p class="slideCaption">
                      <p>5 Liam Payne Hair Evolution</p>
                      Yup, lookin' fresh Liam!                  </p>
                    <p class="slideCredit">
                      Field                 </p>
                  </div> <!--slideInfo end-->
                  <div class="fix"></div>
                </div> <!--slideContainer end-->
               <!--end if each if-->


                <div class="slideContainer">
                  <div class="slide">
                    <span class="slideMiddle"></span><img src="http://onedirectionconnection.com/jquery/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/2014.jpg">
                  </div>
                  <div class="slideInfo">
                    <p class="slideCaption">
                      <p>1 Liam Payne Hair Evolution</p>
                      Fresh new style!                  </p>
                    <p class="slideCredit">
                      Google                    </p>
                  </div> <!--slideInfo end-->
                </div> <!--slideContainer end-->
               <!--end if each if-->
             <!--end each-->
        </div><!--slideshow end-->
        <div class="slideNav">
            <div class="prevSlide">
              <i class="fa fa-chevron-left fa-2x"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="slideCount"></div>
            <div class="nextSlide">
              <i class="fa fa-chevron-right fa-2x"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="fix"></div>
        </div>
     <!--end if-->
  </div> <!--postContainer end-->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following line of code in your script

```
$(".slideshow").height($(".slideContainer").height());
```

Update js fiddle for your reference

http://jsfiddle.net/t534v/5/